# Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip'

Tags: android, gradle, testfairy

I want to upload my app to testfairy. This always worked fine but since I have updated my gradle to 5.1.1 distribution I get the following error:

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:71)
    at com.testfairy.plugin.intellij.BuildAndSendToTestFairy.getTestFairyTasks(BuildAndSendToTestFairy.java:171)
    at com.testfairy.plugin.intellij.BuildAndSendToTestFairy.access$300(BuildAndSendToTestFairy.java:30)
    at com.testfairy.plugin.intellij.BuildAndSendToTestFairy$2.run(BuildAndSendToTestFairy.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:727)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:403)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.UnsupportedVersionException: Support for clients using a tooling API version older than 3.0 was removed in Gradle 5.0. You are currently using tooling API version 2.2. You should upgrade your tooling API client to version 3.0 or later.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.unsupportedConnectionException(DefaultConnection.java:261)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.checkUnsupportedTapiVersion(DefaultConnection.java:275)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.validateAndConvert(DefaultConnection.java:253)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.getModel(DefaultConnection.java:191)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.produceModel(CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher$1.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher$1.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:76)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    ... 3 more
```

When i only start the gradle process it works fine and on all my test phones it also works, so what is the problem?

## gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

## app build.gradle testfairy implementation

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       maven { url 'https://www.testfairy.com/maven' }
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.testfairy.plugins.gradle:testfairy:2.+'
   }
}
apply plugin: 'testfairy'
android {
   testfairyConfig {
       apiKey 'xxxxxx'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> `UnsupportedVersionException`: Support for clients using a tooling API version older than 3.0 was removed in Gradle 5.0. You are currently using tooling API version 2.2. You should upgrade your tooling API client to version 3.0 or later.

Test-fairy obviously still uses tooling API version 2.2... you could file an [issue](https://github.com/testfairy/testfairy-gradle-plugin/issues).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Sabina for this. We are working on releasing a new version shortly with tooling API version 3.0.

As a side note -- I noticed you put your API key here. It's not meant to be shared, and we have revoked this key. Please go to Account Settings -> API Key -> and click on the "Regenerate" button.

I will comment once we have tested and released a Gradle with updated tooling API.

Comment: Oh thank you it was late and I didn't saw that with the api key! how long will it take releasing a new version?

Comment: New version has been released a few days ago. Can you please try again? We have released version 3.0 of both Android Studio addon, and the Gradle Uploader plugin. Thanks for the wait and support!